# How can I know when a value is “re-selected” in a UltraComboEditor?

Tags: winforms, infragistics, ultracombo

Similar threads:
[How can I know when a value is "re-selected" in a ComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326513/how-can-i-know-when-a-value-is-re-selected-in-a-combobox)
[What event handler to use for ComboBox Item Selected (Selected Item not necessarily changed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966264/what-event-handler-to-use-for-combobox-item-selected-selected-item-not-necessar)

I am using Infragistics UltraComobEditor to show some values by filling it's ValueList property with items. The selected item is just like a template and it require to update all elements which are using that template.

To apply it again i need to fire it's SelectionChangeCommitted event, but it does not fire if item is already selected.

I am in the quest to find the drop down list element which was selected before the **DropDownClosed** event fire. Is there any way to get which element was selected or get the element  under the mouse point after the **DropDown** event?

Comment: If the selection is already made and hasn't actually changed, why do you need to respond to the selection changing?  Maybe the selection should have been cleared in the drop down control when it was made invalid.

Comment: There is no case of invalid selection. It is just like that a paper has template which was changed externally and you want that template to apply it again whenever again browse that paper for the page. So there is two way either make that template selection again in dropdown or put a button to reapply it again.

Comment: In that case it would make more sense to have a button (or something else other than dropping down the editor to select the already selected item) to reapply the template as it would be clearer what action is being done.  If you wanted a button embedded into the UltraComboEditor, you could look into using the Editor Buttons to provide an option to reapply the template.